# Named tuple in dictionary?

Tags: c#, .net

i'm trying to create a dictionary with a string key and a tuple value(string, bool). I'd like to make the tuple a named one, so something like:

```
Dictionary<string, (string, bool)> spColumnMapping = new Dictionary<string, 
(string, bool)>();
```

Is it possible?

Thanks

Comment: What did the compiler tell you when you tried it?

Comment: ` Dictionary<String, Tuple<String, Boolean>> dict = new  Dictionary<String, Tuple<String, Boolean>>();`

Comment: `var spColumnMapping = new Dictionary<string, (string name, bool theBool)>();`. Works.

Comment: @KennethK. That line compiles fine, the problem is i don't know how to name the properties in the tuple. I tried doing it in the next statement but i got a warning saying the names would be ignored since they weren't defined when the tuple was created.

Comment: It is totally unclear to me what the problem is. Why didn't named tuples work in your case? Did you try just putting the names in?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
void Main()
{
    Dictionary<string, (string Foo, bool Bar)> spColumnMapping = new Dictionary<string, (string, bool)>();

    spColumnMapping.Add("foo", ("Quax", false));

    var x = spColumnMapping["foo"];

    Console.WriteLine(x.Foo); // prints Quax
    Console.WriteLine(x.Bar); // prints False
}
```

Just name the parameters after the type.

Comment: Yep. You can also use `var` and name the elements of the tuple in the `new` expression, like so: `var spColumnMapping = new Dictionary<string, (string Foo, bool Bar)>();`. I think this is a lot easier to parse mentally when you have a complex type.

Comment: I found that even with naming the tuples as above, when using `TryGetValue` I had to write `if (spColumnMapping.TryGetValue("foo", out (string Foo, bool Bar) item)) { 
Console.WriteLine(${item.Foo}, {item.Bar}"); }`